# Can't Chose the correct shape for train image dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use the CNN architecture I've developed to train imbalanced data model and evaluate its performance.

This is my code:

```py
# Import necessary libraries
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert one-hot encoded labels back to their integer form
train_labels_copy = np.argmax(train_labels, axis=1)

# Split data into airplane/car and others
airplane_car_indices = np.where((train_labels_copy == 0) | (train_labels_copy == 1))[0]
other_indices = np.where((train_labels_copy != 0) & (train_labels_copy != 1))[0]

# Separate airplane/car and other images and labels
airplane_car_images = train_images[airplane_car_indices]
airplane_car_labels = train_labels[airplane_car_indices]  # use train_labels instead of train_labels_copy
other_images = train_images[other_indices]
other_labels = train_labels[other_indices]  # use train_labels instead of train_labels_copy

# Shuffle the airplane/car indices
np.random.shuffle(airplane_car_indices)

# Calculate 20% of the airplane and car class data
remove_n = int(0.2 * len(airplane_car_indices))

# Keep only 20% of airplane and car class data
airplane_car_images = airplane_car_images[:remove_n]
airplane_car_labels = airplane_car_labels[:remove_n]

# Combine imbalanced airplane/car and other data
train_images_imbalanced = np.concatenate((airplane_car_images, other_images))
train_labels_imbalanced = np.concatenate((airplane_car_labels, other_labels))

# Shuffle the imbalanced data
train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced = shuffle(train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced)

# Train the same model on the imbalanced data
history_imbalanced = cnn.fit(train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

# Plot the loss and accuracy graphs
plot_loss_and_accuracy(history_imbalanced)

# Predict the test data
predictions_imbalanced = cnn.predict(test_images)

# Convert prediction probabilities to class labels
predictions_imbalanced = np.argmax(predictions_imbalanced, axis=1)

# Print the classification report
print(classification_report(np.argmax(test_labels, axis=1), predictions_imbalanced, target_names=class_names))
```

The error is:

```
Epoch 1/20
1312/1313 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.4442 - accuracy: 0.8443
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 37
     34 train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced = shuffle(train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced)
     36 # Train the same model on the imbalanced data
---> 37 history_imbalanced = cnn.fit(train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))
     39 # Plot the loss and accuracy graphs
     40 plot_loss_and_accuracy(history_imbalanced)

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filesf8xdq9z.py:15, in outer_factory..inner_factory..tf__test_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:
...
    File "c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5559, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
```

I tried To fix this issue, with convert the labels in `train_labels_imbalanced` to categorical format using the `to_categorical` function from Keras utils. I replaced the following line:

```py
train_labels_imbalanced = np.concatenate((airplane_car_labels, other_labels))
```

with:

```py
train_labels_imbalanced = np.concatenate((to_categorical(airplane_car_labels, num_classes=10), other_labels))
```

and but I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 31
     29 # Combine imbalanced airplane/car and other data
     30 train_images_imbalanced = np.concatenate((airplane_car_images, other_images))
---> 31 train_labels_imbalanced = np.concatenate((to_categorical(airplane_car_labels, num_classes=10), other_labels))
     33 # Shuffle the imbalanced data
     34 train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced = shuffle(train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that something went wrong with your validation data shapes:
history_imbalanced = cnn.fit(train_images_imbalanced, train_labels_imbalanced, batch_size=32, epochs=20, validation_data=(test_images, test_labels))

So here, how do you create test_images, test_labels?
As you can see in the first log you gave the epoch training was done, but then when starting to evaluate the validation data the error (probably you forgot to apply hot_coding on the test_labels) was raise.